# Projection of a hypersurface from a point

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, blow-ups

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. We consider the projective space $\mathbb P_n$ over defined over $k$, the point $Q=(0:\dots:1)$, the hyperplane $H=\{X_n=0\}$ and a hypersurface $X$. We want to study the image of $X$ under the projection from $Q$ to $H$. If $Q\notin X$ everything is clear and every point $(x_0:\dots:x_n)\in X$ is mapped to $(x_0:\dots:x_{n-1}:0)$.

What happens if $Q\in X$? I've read that the projection must be thought using the blow up but I am still confused... what does the projection look like? I need this to (try to) extend a result but I would like to walk on "solid ground". To be precise, I am interested in the actual shape of the map and, in particular, in the ramification divisor.

I found hundreds of examples about blowing up the affine plane at the origin, dozens about an affine curve but it looks like nobody wants to lose time giving details in in this case...

A reference or a few hints would be very appreciated!

Comment: The image will be the whole $H$ though!

Comment: Not if $Q\in X$. For instance, let $X$ be defined by $X_0X_2+X_1^2$ and $Q$ be the point $(0:0:1)$. The point $(0:1:0)$ does not belong to the projection. On the other hand, if $Q\notin X$, the projection is surjective.

Comment: If you consider the projection as a morphism from $X$ blown up at $Q$, the projection is always surjective, unless $X$ is a cone. This is the only reasonable approach.

Comment: @abx: Could you please be more specific? For instance, in the example I made above, which points are mapped to $(0:1:0)$?

Comment: The point $Q$ itself maps to $(0:1:0)$. All of this is very elementary and would be more appropriate on MSE.

Comment: No answers on MSE... would you please show me the steps to write down the projection (even just in the example I made)?

Comment: I ended up voting to leave this open, although it is quite elementary and I'm conflicted about the vote.  I'm slightly confused, you seem to be able to write down the projection almost everywhere.  So you get a rational map certainly, then the question is whether or not it extends over the point. After blowing up, you know it extends (see the bit in Hartshorne on blowups), but Q may or may not map to a unique point from the original X (consider the cone example abx pointed out). If the inverse image of Q maps to a unique point, then so does Q. This even works for non-hypersurfaces.

Comment: The rational map is easy to understand. Then I can blow up $X$ at $Q$ (even if I would have enjoyed more details in the books I read). What I don't know is how to write down the resulting map from the blow up.

Comment: In your specific example the projection is $(X_0:X_1:X_2)\mapsto (X_0:X_1:0)$ on $X-Q$, $(X_0:X_1:X_2)\mapsto (-X_1:X_2:0)$ on $X-(1:0:0)$.

Comment: It is a bit harsh to downvote and vote for closing: Wesley has asked on MSE and has not received an answer that satisfies him. What is he supposed to do now?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I think it would have been preferable for knowledgable users to answer Wesley at MSE instead. Here is the link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883801/projection-of-a-hypersurface-from-a-point. This was also discussed at MO meta: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1810/elementary-questions

Comment: @Todd: in principle I agree, but not all MO users are also active on MSE (I haven't any MSE account, for instance).

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Of course I know this, but signing up on another StackExchange site just takes a minute. (This is really a meta concern, but perhaps a discussion should be had about greater cross-fertilization between the sites. Meanwhile, some good points were made in the meta discussion I linked to.)

Comment: @Todd: Yes, but maybe some users just do not feel like signing up on MSE, not even for answering a single question (for instance because they do not like the site, or because they are already too busy with MO). At any rate, I agree that this is more a meta concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that this question is perhaps not suitable for MO. Anyway, as you received no satisfactory answers on MSE, let me give you some examples that (I hope) can improve a bit your understanding of the situation. You are strongly encouraged to fill the details by yourself.

**Example 1.** Take a smooth quadric surface $X \subset \mathbf{P}^2$ and consider the projection $\pi_P \colon  X \dashrightarrow \mathbf{P}^2$, where $p \in X$. The birational map $\pi_P$ is *not* defined at the point $p$, and it induces a birational morphism $\hat{\pi} \colon \widehat{X} \to \mathbf{P}^2$, where $\widehat{X}$ is the blow-up of $X$ at $p$. The morphism $\pi$ contracts the two lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ of $X$ passing through $p$ to two points $q_1,  \, q_2 \in \mathbf{P}^2$. The image of the exceptional divisor $E \subset \widehat{X}$ is the line $\overline{q_1 q_2}$.

**Example 2.** Take a smooth cubic surface $X  \subset \mathbf{P}^2$ and consider the projection $\pi_P \colon  X \dashrightarrow \mathbf{P}^2$, where $p \in X$. The birational map $\pi_P$ is *not* defined at the point $p$ and has generically degree $2$. It induces a flat double cover $\hat{\pi} \colon \widehat{X} \to \mathbf{P}^2$, where $\widehat{X}$ is the blow-up of $X$ at $p$, whose branch locus is a smooth quartic curve $B \subset \mathbf{P}^2$. It is well known (Plücker formulas) that $B$ has precisely $28$ bitangents. They arise as follows: $27$ of them are the images of the $27$ lines on the cubic surface, and the remaining one is the image of the exceptional divisor $E \subset \widehat{X}$.

**Example 3.** In this example the center of the projection is a singular point of $X$. Take a Kummer quartic surface $X \subset \mathbf{P}^2$, i.e. a quartic with $16$ nodes, and choose a node $p$. The birational map $\pi_P \colon X \dashrightarrow \mathbf{P}^2$ is *not* defined at the point $p$ and has generically degree $2$. It induces a flat double cover $\hat{\pi} \colon \widehat{X} \to \mathbf{P}^2$, where $\widehat{X}$ is the blow-up of $X$ at $p$, whose branch locus is a sextic curve $B \subset \mathbf{P}^2$, that splits as the union of six lines $L_1, \ldots, L_6$. These lines intersects pairwise in $6(6-1)/2=15$ points, that correspond to the $15$ nodes of $\widehat{X}$. The exceptional divisor $E \subset \widehat{X}$ is mapped to a conic $C$ which is tangent to all the $L_i$: in particular, the $L_i$ are *not* in general position.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your effort and I am grateful for your examples. I am goign to work on them as soon as I click on "Add Comment"!